# JavaScript: Call Class Object's Function to Add Values Into An Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, methods

I have the code below which defines an object "ideas" and creates a class object called "Goals":

```
let ideas = {};

class Goals {
  constructor () {

  }
}
```

And then I have another code chunk below that shows a list of functions that I will call on my class object:

```
module.exports = {
  reset: function() {
    ideas = {}; 
  },
  add: function(name, task) {
    // saves a task for a given person
    ideas[name] = task;
  }
};

Goals.add("college", { content: "apply to 4 schools" });
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Goals.add is not a function
```

I am hoping to see the following returned in the tasks object:

```
{ college: [{apply to 4 schools}] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no relationship between that first code example, and the second. Why do you think Goals has an `add` method?

Comment: hm, okay; how can I access the add method given my current code setup?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why are the methods you want Goals to use separate from the class?

Comment: I see, I need to add the functions as methods to my class?

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd want them separate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking something like this.

```js
class Goals {
  constructor() {
    this.ideas = {};
  }
  reset() {
    this.ideas = {};
  }
  add(name, task) {
    // saves a task for a given person
    this.ideas[name] = task;
  }
}

var goal = new Goals();

goal.add("college", {
  content: "apply to 4 schools"
});

console.log(goal);
```

Comment: thx for response, I'm hoping that my code will produce an ideas object that looks like this: ideas = {"college": [{
      "content": "apply to 4 schools"
    }]}

Answer (score 0):

In the current code there is no link between what you export and the method you are calling on the `Goals` class, you need to import that module in the code where you defined the `class Goals` and add the required functions imported as *static* methods in the class for example:

```js
    //const action = require('path/to/add/reset/module'); if your intention is to make it re-usable
    //emulating an import
    const action = {
          reset: function() {
          ideas = {}; 
      },
          add: function(name, task) {
          // saves a task for a given person
          ideas[name] = ideas[name] ? ideas[name].concat(task) : [task];
      }
    };

    let ideas = {};
    
    class Goals {
      constructor () {
    
      }
      
      static add(name, task){
        action.add(name, task);
      }
      
      add(name, task){
        action.add(name, task);
      }
    
    }
    Goals.add("college", { content: "apply to 4 schools" });
    console.log(ideas);
    //better way
    const goals = new Goals();
    goals.add("college", { content: "apply to 2 schools" });
    console.log(ideas);
```

Comment: @Andy is there any issue with this logic? :)

Comment: I can see at least one problem.

Comment: @Andy please tell me, I will correct it if possible or I will delete this answer :)

Comment: You're calling `add` on the class rather than an instance.

Comment: @Andy Not sure if OP wants to call the method on the class rather than the instance , that is why I made the `add` method static so it can be called on the class. I do not know why OP is putting the `add` and `reset` in a separate module maybe for re-use.  I will wait for OP to respond else I will delete this answer.

Comment: @Andy please see my edit, I also added a version which calls `add` on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Goals should probably hold its own ideas property and methods to manipulate them e.g.

```
class Goals {
  constructor() {
    this.ideas = {};
  }

  add(name, task) {
    this.ideas[name] = task;
  }

  reset() {
    this.ideas = {};
  }
}
```

This is kind of dependent on your use case, but if you ever need to have two distinct Goals objects (i.e. if you have goals for different users) then it is absolutely necessary to have per instance ideas.